# Bundle SQLite3 database into `electron-nuxt` project

Tags: sqlite, electron, nuxt.js

I'm using [electron-nuxt](https://github.com/michalzaq12/electron-nuxt) to develop my desktop application. I would like to ship my app with a SQLite3 database. AFAIK, I need to put the database file into `resources` folder, and use app.getPath('appData) to be able to read/write from/into the database. However, electron doesn't find the database. It does not copy the database, and I don't see the database file anywhere outside my `resources` folder in the source code.

Where does the `resources` get copied to? How do I access my `resources` folder? Docs [told me](https://michalzaq12.github.io/electron-nuxt/guide/#static-resources) that I need to use `app.getPath('appData')` in order to get reference to my resources, but it only gives me the AppData path (`C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming` in Windows) where there are no resources and of course, no database file. Even when I check the `Electron` folder inside `Roaming`, there are no traces of the resources folder.